# AR Drone 2.0 Streaming

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming

The following code is trying to stream a video from an A.R Drone using python. When I run the code, I receive error `error reading video feed`. I am using OPENcv 3.3.0. Maybe I am suppose to download something. I am not entirely sure. I am a newbie to this.

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('tcp://192.168.1.1:5555')
running = True
while running:
    # get current frame of video
    running, frame = cam.read()
    if running:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27: 
            # escape key pressed
            running = False
    else:
        # error reading frame
        print 'error reading video feed'
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: have you double checked your drone has that IP address? and is sending via that same port? What code/software is your a.r. drone using?

Comment: Yes its correct IP address. Is there another to stream this using `Video Capture`